# String from file names - How remove the extension?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, filenames, isolatedstorage

I'm developing a windows phone app. I saved many files on `Isolated storage` and i need shows them (file names) on ListBox.
My code works fine, but file names is show with extension (`filename.doc`). I want show file names without extension (`filename`).

My code:

```
IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

string directory = "./preVenda/*.*";
string[] filenames = myIsolatedStorage.GetFileNames(directory);

List0.Items.Add(filenames);
```

I tried use "Remove" method, but not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
foreach(string file in filenames)
    List0.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));
```

Also, you could try without an explicit loop (I suppose that list0 is a `System.Windows.Control.ListBox`)

```
list0.ItemsSource = filenames.Select(d => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(d)).ToList();
```

(Warning. Not able to test this now)

Comment: Thanks for support, but I received the error: `'System.Windows.Shapes.Path' does not contain a definition for 'GetFileNameWithoutExtension'`

Comment: @ReneSá Use `System.IO.Path`

Comment: Add a using directive to your code `using System.IO;` or add the namespace before the Path class. (`System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(.....)`)